# What is the best way to track down the origin and grammar of this quote?

Tags: quotes, research

> The best way to know a man is to walk a thousand miles in his shoes. That way, he's a  thousand miles away and has no shoes.

I'm willing to bet it's a Jack Handey quote, as it's rather in that vein of thinking, but the question came up, and since "walk a thousand miles in [his] shoes" is so vague, it's hard to pin it down on [insert-random-search-engine-here].

So what's the best way to look up a quote like this (and bonus points for the source attribution / correct quote on this one)?

Comment: Wow, looks like it was Handey. You deduced that from the style alone? Nice.

Comment: @LordT Or that I had seen the original clip at some point in the past and so my brain recognized it. But it definitely has the style of a Handey (take something familiar, then apply BOfH styling to it, but not too over the top)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Johnny Carson, "What I Have Learned," 1991:  “Before you criticize a man, walk a mile in his shoes.  That way, if he's upset, he's a mile away and you've got his shoes."  Handey did start on SNL in 1991 but I don't know when/if he did this gag, which I've also seen attributed to Billy Connolly.  I know about the Carson date because I was his head writer, 1988-92.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I googled "never judge walk mile shoes mile away have his shoes handey" and got [this](http://www.dictionary-quotes.com/never-criticize-a-man-until-you-ve-walked-a-mile-in-his-moccasins-american-indian-proverb/), which says the quote is

> Before you criticize someone, you
>   should walk a mile in their shoes.
>   That way when you criticize them, you
>   are a mile away from them and you have
>   their shoes." – Jack Handey

My technique was to specify a subset of the quote that I thought had the words that most likely actually appeared in the original quote, along with the suspected correct attribution.

Comment: I applaud you for ID'ing that it was _indeed_ a Jack Handey quote ... I tried the "subset of the quote" but apparently my subset was off. Bravissimo to you. Can you think of a better way to refine quotes to trim down to unique key words? (my CS brain just started churning on an algorithm and now I think there must already be a well defined way to find these sparse posts)

Comment: It seems like asking a lot for there to be such a thing. :)  What I mainly try to do is leave out the parts where I'm unsure of the original phrasing; I got "never judge" wrong above, which I'm sure hurt me, but I guess not that badly.  I also didn't try to cut down to unique keywords; notice that I duplicated "mile" and "shoes".  That's because I'm under the impression that Google calculates additional relevance from sequence matches (I wanted "mile away" and "have his shoes" to appear in a matchable sequence).

Comment: +1 I was going to post an answer with the same quote. My technique was the same, except that I chose the following words: *[quote know a man thousand miles shoes "no shoes"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=quote+miles+away+and+has+no+shoes.&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB%3Aofficial&q=quote+know+a+man+thousand+miles+shoes+%22no+shoes%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=39ef0641b36cef54)*. Notice that I did not even need to include *jack handey* to get the same link on the first results page.

Comment: @Bruno Rothgiesser: Ah, so.  Your google-fu is strong.